# Unexpected animation stack behavior on View

Tags: animation, swiftui

The documentation says

> `.animation(, value:)`  Applies the given animation to this view when the specified value
> changes.

When I have stack animations stack on my view, it is understandable that animation modifier animates all changed until its line after modifier changes shouldn't animate, that's fine until two animations.
When I add the third animation on the stack, this third change is affected by the first animation which is commented as below.

Is there any explanation for that? Am I missing something or this is a bug?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    @State private var half = false
    @State private var dim = false
    @State private var isBlack = false
    @State private var isRotated = false
    
    // MARK: View
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .rotationEffect(isRotated ? .degrees(180) : .degrees(0))
            .opacity(dim ? 0.2 : 1.0)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: dim) // animates half, isblack and isRotated
            .scaleEffect(half ? 0.5 : 1.0)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 5.0), value: half) // animates only half
            .foregroundColor(isBlack ? .black : .blue)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 15.0).delay(5), value: isBlack) // doesnt have any effect
            .onTapGesture {
                dim.toggle()
                half.toggle()
                isBlack.toggle()
                isRotated.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is gif of issue?

Comment: You have several problems with your code. First, you really should be using explicit, not implicit animations. Explicit is coded using a `withAnimation()` around the variable you are changing. The second, and bigger issue is you can really only run 1 animation at a time. You have 3 animations that are essentially the same that are all trying to run at once. If you do want this behavior, they have to run sequentionally which means the change will have to be run in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)`, otherwise they conflict.